# Different threads don't work together while doing different tasks

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm creating two different threads which will solve same problem with different ways and I will calculate their solving time. I've created a structure like that;

MainController.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainController mc= new MainController();
        mc.setProblem();
        Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1("thread1",problem,approach1);
        Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2("thread2",problem,approach2);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
```

Thread1.java

```
class Thread1 implements Runnable{

       public void run() {
          System.out.println("Running " +  threadName );
          try {
             solve(approach);
          } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " interrupted.");
          }
          //showTable();
          System.out.println("Thread " +  threadName + " exiting.");
       }

       public void start () {
          System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
          if (t == null) {
             t = new Thread (this, threadName);
             t.start ();
          }
       }

       public void solve(approach) throws Exception {

            // Throw an exception to stop the process if the puzzle is solved
            if (didIsolve())  {//true if yes
                    System.out.println("----" + threadName +"----");
                    showResult();
                    System.out.println("--------------------------");
                    throw new Exception("ex");
            }
        }
    }
```

Thread2.java is the same as above code block.

And output like

```
    Creating thread1
    Creating thread2
    Starting thread1
    Starting thread2
    Running thread2
    Running thread1
    Thread thread1 exiting.
    ----thread2----
   RESULT METHOD OUTPUT
    --------------------------
    Thread thread2 interrupted.
    Thread thread2 exiting.
```

As you see above, thread1 did not solve problem, at least did not show result.

Also I've checked this topics so far

[multiple threads performing different tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10909251/multiple-threads-performing-different-tasks)

[Java threads to do different tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9916366/java-threads-to-do-different-tasks)

Edit:

Well, I think I found the problem. I changed MainController class;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainController mc= new MainController();
        mc.setProblem();
        MainController mc2 = new MainContoller();
        mc1.setProblem();
        Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1("thread1",mc.problem,approach1);
        Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2("thread2",mc1.problem,approach2);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
```

And it worked, but I don't know why. I will not accept my answer as correct answer for few days, may someone explain this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found the problem. I changed MainController class;

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MainController mc= new MainController();
        mc.setProblem();
        MainController mc2 = new MainContoller();
        mc1.setProblem();
        Thread1 thread1 = new Thread1("thread1",mc.problem,approach1);
        Thread2 thread2 = new Thread2("thread2",mc1.problem,approach2);
        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
    }
```

And it worked, but I don't know why. I will not accept my answer as correct answer for few days, may someone explain this situation?

Comment: If this solved your problem, then you haven't posted enough information in your question about your code and your issue by far - it's impossible to reach this solution based on the information in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to measure the solving time of each approach, doing it in a multithreaded way is not going to give you consistent and reliable results. It would be better to run each approach in a serial fashion, and probably many times, to get an average completion time of each approach. Take care to avoid taxing the CPU with other processes during the test.

Comment: Not just measuring solving time, also I need to see solving progress, and it must be at same time. But thanks for advice.

Comment: Try calling thread.join() on each thread after starting both.

Comment: They are working in order now. Thread2 is starting after thread1's die.